# Java array days

Tags: java, arrays

I have this method that allows the user to search an array with days with a string
I missplaced my catch Exception somewhere because I can't get that to work. And the sysout prints Please enter a day two times, I don't know where to place it. Otherwise the method prints the day if its written right.

```
public void getDay() {

    String days[] = {"", "Monday", "Tuesday", "Wednesday",
        "Thursday", "Friday", "Saturday", "Sunday"};
    boolean isbol = true;



    while (isbol) {
        try {
            System.out.println("Please enter a day: ");
            day = in.nextLine();

            for (int i = 1; i < days.length; i++) {

                if (day.equals(days[i])) {
                    System.out.println(i + 1);
                    isbol = false;

                }

            }
        } catch (Exception e) {
            System.out.println("Wrong input, please try again");
        }

    }

}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think it's not necessary to use try/catch, simplt if/else is enough and easy.

```
    String days[] = { "", "Monday", "Tuesday", "Wednesday", "Thursday",
            "Friday", "Saturday", "Sunday" };
    boolean finish = false; // use a readable variable name

    while (!finish) {
        System.out.println("Please enter a day: ");
        day = in.nextLine();
        for (int i = 1; i < days.length; i++) {
            if (day.equalsIgnoreCase(days[i])) { // match upper and lower case
                System.out.println("the index of day in the array is " + (i + 1));
                finish = true;
                break; // stop the loop if found the day in array
            }
        }
        if (!finish)
            System.out.println("Can't find " + day
                    + " in the array, please try again!");
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

You shouldn't be using a `try/catch` here. You aren't throwing any exceptions, you are simply trying to evaluate a condition. This is why the exception is never called.

I think this is what you are going for:

```
        //added this to get the program to compile on my machine
        String day; 
        Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in); 

         String days[] = {"", "Monday", "Tuesday", "Wednesday",
                    "Thursday", "Friday", "Saturday", "Sunday"};
                boolean isbol = true;



                while (isbol) {
                        System.out.println("Please enter a day: ");
                        day = in.nextLine();

                        for (int i = 1; i < days.length; i++) {

                            if (day.equals(days[i])) {
                                //I assume you are trying to output the day here.
                                System.out.println(days[i]);
                                isbol = false;

                            }


                        }
                        //Conditional check to see if the user input a day
                        if(isbol){

                                System.out.println("Wrong input, please try again");  
                        }
                }

}
```

Also, keep in mind that the way this is set up, the loop will only break if you type a day like `Monday`. If you type `monday` the loop will continue.

Comment: Ok, took away the try/catch but the first output when the method runs is like this:                                                                                                   Please enter a day: 
Wrong input, please try again
Please enter a day:

Comment: What are you inputting when the program asks you for a day? The way I have it set up here works. I've tested it on my machine.

Comment: This is before I enter a day, otherwise it works perfect but it prints those tree lines

Comment: If I were you, I'd copy my code exactly, and try that. I'm not seeing the problem you are talking about. From there you can adjust it as you need to for your method. It may also have to do with how you are calling the method.

Comment: It worked. I had two methods before this that run and when I started with this method everything was ok

Answer (score 0):

I guess you want to catch error when there is no match in days array. Because no run time exception is thrown when there is no match, your catch clause will never be executed.
One solution is to add an If statement that throws exception when the for loop is exhausted.

```
public static void main(String[] args){
    Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
    String days[] = {"", "Monday", "Tuesday", "Wednesday",
            "Thursday", "Friday", "Saturday", "Sunday"};
    boolean isbol = true;

    while (isbol) {
        try {
            System.out.println("Please enter a day: ");
            String day = input.nextLine();

            for (int i = 1; i < days.length; i++) {

                if (day.equalsIgnoreCase(days[i])) {
                    System.out.println(i + 1);
                    isbol = false;
                }
            }
            if(isbol)
                throw new Exception();
        } catch (Exception e) {
            System.out.println("Wrong input, please try again");
        }

    }
    input.close();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you are filling in `System.in` somewhere in the code, that's why you get "Please Enter a day: " message twice. Also, you don't need any exception handling. Below you can find the modified version of the code. Use `System.in` inside the method and close it.

```
public int getDay() {
    Scanner in = null;
    try {
        in = new Scanner(System.in);
        String days[] = { "", "Monday", "Tuesday", "Wednesday", "Thursday", "Friday", "Saturday", "Sunday" };
        for (;;) {
            System.out.println("Please enter a day: ");
            String day = in.nextLine();
            for (int i = 1; i < days.length; i++) {
                if (day.equalsIgnoreCase(days[i])) {
                    System.out.println(i+1);
                    return i + 1;
                }
            }
        }
    } finally {
        in.close();
    }
}
```